# I’m trying to make all the images on my site duotone without having to use pseudo-elements and wrappers. (Trying to keep the HTML clean)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-selectors

Currently, I've been using [this tutorial](https://jmperezperez.com/blog/duotone-using-css-blend-modes/). But it is just not as clean As I'd have hoped, and I'm sure there is a better alternative.

I know I can do this:

```css
.img-wrap{
    position: relative;
}
.img-wrap img{
    filter: grayscale(1);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
.img-wrap::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100/">
</div>
```

But I want to accomplish this without having to use a wrapper.

Comment: Please use a code editor to type your code (or something that doesn't convert quotes to "curly quotes" because those don't work in HTML, or CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SVG filters to do this.

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
  filter: url(#duotone);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100"/>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="duotone">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" >
    </feColorMatrix>
    <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone">
      <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 1"></feFuncR>
      <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncG>
      <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncB>
      <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
    </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

The way this works is:

1. We define the filter as `#duotone` in our SVG.
2. We convert the image to grayscale feColorMatrix.
3. Finally, we apply a RGBA filter on top of that image. These values are set via the tableValues. The first of two values being the amount (from 0 → 1). A common way to understand this is by taking the RGBA values you are used to and dividing them by 255 (since thats the max). For example, a red value of 100 would be `100/255=0.3921` OR `<feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.3921 1"></feFuncR>`.